# Store data in DB so primary key is known before insertion based on data to be inserted

Tags: sql, image-processing, coldfusion, hash, apache2

The basic gist of what I'm trying to accomplish is setting up an image processing server. As the page code is created in Coldfusion multiple images on the page may need to be resized and thumbnailed into appropriate sizes, each to a possibly different size and each with a possibly different algorithm.

The basic gist of how it works is using a simple img tag the src attribute will point to the image server along the lines of the following.

`<img src="http://imageserver.com/<clientname>/<primarykey>.jpg">`

This allows the image resizing to occur asynchronously, and on a different server, thus not slowing down the current page call.

When the image processing server receives the call it will first check if that file exists, if Apache determines the file exists it serves it right away, else, it invokes Coldfusion which reads an entry from the database using the primary key passed to it, to get the URL of the image to be processed and any associated parameters (in this case width, height, method, url, client, but possibly more in the future).

Currently I'm doing this using a hash system where the parameters are ordered alphabetically, and then hashed. Is that a reasonable system, or will hash collisions eventually occur even though the data being hashed is quite small (between 50 to 200 characters). Each client could likely store up to 10,000 images (in their own folder so hash collision would not be a problem cross-client).

To reduce DB calls, as the page processes, each time a processed image is desired, I add that image's information to an array. At the end of the page, I make 2 calls to the DB, first it checks if the rows in my array already exist in the DB, and then if necessary, it adds any rows that do not exist (storing their various parameters). The dilemma here is that the primarykey (or what goes in the image tag) must be known *before* it is actually inserted into the DB, this way I'm not checking at every single image as some pages could have hundreds of images on them and that would be very inefficient.

Are hash collisions not a concern with this sample size (10k images per client generated by 50-200 character strings)? What about if I did something simple like `<width>_<height>_<hash>.jpg` or put the images in folders like `/<client>/<width>x<height>/<hash>.jpg` because that would further reduce the possibility of hash collisions (although not remove them)?

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you hashing? Use SHA-512 for the hashing algorithm and you'll get a string 128 characters long. You may not want a URL so long, but the idea here is that you can minimize collisions via more complex algorithms.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c52.html

Comment: Currently: `hash("#data.image#_#data.width#_#data.height#_#data.method#")`

Comment: I did something similar, I lcase the keys and sort the `data` struct using a Java `HashMap`, and then hash the `SerializeJSON` of that struct to determine my unique identifier. So far we've yet to have a collision with about 100,000 records.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I doubt you would have to worry about hash collisions, you may want to just use a UUID.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-70de.html

EDIT: Or use a uniqueidentifer as the primary key of the table you are storing the file to.  Then after an insert, you can use the OUTPUT clause of a query to return the key to be used however you want.

Answer (score 0):

The method I resolved this was by hashing not only the filename but it's parameters, such as width and height. Thus, the possibility of hash collisions is basically 0 until we hit millions (billions?) of records. So far we have no hash collisions.